# Multiple collections relation

Tags: c#, xaml, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I have few collections on one of my ViewModels that are related both directly and indirectly to this object. Is big simplification it is something like:

```
public class PatientViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string ID { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<VisitViewModel> Visits { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<TreatmentViewModel> Treatments{ get; }

    public ObservableCollection<MedicationViewModel> Medications{ get; }

    public PatientViewModel(string id)
    {
        ID = id;

        Visits = Factory.GenerateCollection(EntityType.Visit, id);

        Treatments= Factory.GenerateCollection(EntityType.Treatment, id);

        Medications= Factory.GenerateCollection(EntityType.Medication, id);
    }
}


public class VisitViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string ID { get; }
    private string PatientID { get; }
    ...
}

public class TreatmentViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private string ID { get; }
    private string VisitID { get; }
    private string PatientID { get; }
    ...
}

public class MedicationViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private string ID { get; }
    private string TreatmentID { get; }
    private string PatientID { get; }
    ...
}
```

I could possibly create hierarchical chain between those three collections, but don't want to because:

- multiple aggregations done at PatientViewModel (like hasMedicationLike, hadVisitInLastYear, hasUnsuccessfulTreatments, etc)
- initial loading time (getting 3 big collections from sql is much faster than singles loaded by traversing each node)

Question:
How to configure collection view source grouping in a way, that the view like this could be generated:
[image]

Comment: Would you consider a viewmodel property that returns a LINQ query that cobbles together that view via a join, out of what's in those three observablecollections?

Comment: I have all the data I need on my hand, the problem is to group it. Using <ItemsControl.GroupStyle><GroupStyle.ContainerStyle> makes it loose the DataContext, so I cannot relate to PatientViewModel anymore